# Are application helper methods available to all views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

```
Rails 4.1
Ruby 2.0
Windows 8.1
```

In my helpers/application_helper.rb, I have:

```
def agents_and_ids_generator
    agents = Agent.all.order(:last)
    if agents
      agents_and_ids = [['','']]
      agents.each do |l|
        name = "#{l.first} #{l.last}"
        agents_and_ids << [name,l.id]
      end
      return agents_and_ids
    end
  end
```

In my views/agents/form.html.erb, I have the following:

```
<%= f.select :agent_id, options_for_select(agents_and_ids_generator) %>
```

In my controllers/agents_controller.rb, I have the following:

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

But when I go to this view, I get the following error message:

undefined local variable or method `agents_and_ids_generator' for #<#:0x00000006fc9148>

If I move the agents_and_ids_generator method to the helpers/agents_helper.rb, it works fine.

I thought that by putting methods in the application helper and including the application in a controller, then these methods are available to the views. Am I incorrect in that assumption?

## Answer:

Making sure that application helper is not included in controllers, and added the following simplification:

```
<%= f.collection_select :agent_id, Agent.all.order(:last), :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true %>

#app/models/agent.rb
Class Agent < ActiveRecord::Base
   def name_with_initial
     "#{self.first} #{self.last}"
   end
end
```

Comment: you do not have to `include ApplicationHelper` in your controller

Comment: yes but that does not explain the issue I'm asking about

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Helpers**

The bottom line answer is the `application_helper` *is* available in all your views.

Rails actually uses helpers all over the place - in everything from the likes of `form_for` to other built-in Rails methods.

As Rails is basically just a series of classes & modules, the `helpers` are loaded when your views are rendered, allowing you to call them whenever you need. `Controllers` are processed much earlier in the stack, and thus you have to explicitly include the helpers you need in them

**Important** - you don't need to include the `ApplicationHelper` in your `ApplicationController`. It *should* just work

---

**Your Issue**

There may be several potentialities causing the problem; I have two ideas for you:

> 1. Is your `AgentsController` inheriting from `ApplicationController`?
> 2. Perhaps your inclusion of `ApplicationHelper` is causing an issue

Its strange that your `AgentsHelper` works, and `ApplicationHelper` does not. One way to explain this would be that Rails will load a helper depending on the controller which is being operated, meaning if you don't inherit from `ApplicationController,` the `ApplicationHelper` won't be called.

You'll need to test with this:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class AgentsController < ApplicationController
   ...
end
```

Next, you need to get rid of the `include ApplicationHelper` in your controller. This only makes the helper available for that class (the controller), and will not have any bearing on your view

Having said this, it *may* be causing a problem with your view loading the `ApplicationHelper` - meaning you should definitely test removing it from your `ApplicationController`

---

**Method**

Finally, your method could be simplified massively, using [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select):

```
<%= f.collection_select :agent_id, Agent.all.order(:last), :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true %>

#app/models/agent.rb
Class Agent < ActiveRecord::Base
   def name_with_initial
       "#{l.first} #{l.last}"
   end
end
```

Comment: including application_helper in the controller was a Hail Mary. It was not not there initially knowing that the application_helper methods are automatically available to all views. I'll check for anything else that may be unusual. Thanks for the simplified method.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please let me know what's wrong with the answer. I'm leaving it unchanged for the simple fact that I believe it to be correct.

Comment: Not sure why this got voted down but I find it very irritating when someone votes down an answer or a question without leaving a comment. I think this should be a requirement for this type of forum. I am accepting your answer with one minor modification for the model method

Comment: Thanks - I don't mind downvotes; I just want to know how I can improve to make it better for next time

Answer (score 2):

Rails 5 update. I ran into a similar issue with views not picking up a method from application_helper.rb. [This post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170704091413/https://rubyplus.com/articles/3651-Custom-View-Helpers-in-Rails-5) helped me. The files that are provided in the helpers directory of a new rails app are for those views only. Methods in the application_helper.rb will not be available automatically to all views. To create a helper method that is available to all views, create a new helper file in the helper directory such as `clean_emails_helper.rb` and add your custom method here like this:

```
Module CleanEmailsHelper
  def clean_email(email)
     *do some stuff to email*
     return email
  end
end
```

Then you can call `<%= clean_email(email) %>` from any view in your app.